# How To Make V-key Toggle Between Vertex Paint And Object Mode?

Tags: interface, customization, shortcut

I am trying to set up <kbd>V</kbd>-Key as shortcut. But it is ignored in Vertex Paint Mode.

In Object Mode, I hover over Vertex Paint, right-click and add shortcut.
Great! I hit <kbd>V</kbd>-key, switches to Vertex Paint mode.

Now I hover over Object Mode, right-click and add shortcut.
Since I am trying to toggle states, I use same: <kbd>V</kbd>-Key

[image]

But, it does not switch back to Object Mode.

It seems that shortcuts are global, not bound to current view state.

So, can I make <kbd>V</kbd>-key a toggle between view modes?

Answer (score 1):

It occurred to me I was trying to mimic the <kbd>Tab</kbd>-Key. So I looked that up in the Keymap. Then just did the same thing, but for Vertex Painting instead of Editing.

Preferences > Keymap > 3D View > Object Non-modal > Add New

- Set `object.mode_set`
- Assign <kbd>V</kbd>-Key binding
- Then select option to make it a toggle.

[image]

**Note**: In Vertex Paint mode, <kbd>V</kbd> is already bound to 'Vertex Section' mask. I removed the default <kbd>V</kbd>-key shortcut from Keymap > 3D View > Vertex Paint.